# Extracting top 10 percent from 100 different tables using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, statistics, mysql-variables

I have a database which contains 100 tables with distinct employee_ID and Salary. the total rows in the database is 100 million (sum of all the rows in 100 tables). The tables don't have equal number of rows. let's say the 100 tables are according to regions.
I want to return top 10 % of the salaries from all the tables. How can it be done?

Comment: It can be done with `SELECT` statements. Is there something more specific you want to ask?

Comment: SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE salary>=(SELECT max(salary)*.10 FROM <table>); is that simple.

Comment: i have 100 tables. using a query i want to extract top 10 percent. doing a union all would take a lot of effort and execution time.

Comment: Echoing Gordon's point below, you should have one (properly partitioned) table, not 100! Obviously, your set up will take a lot of effort - but that's your fault - not ours!

Answer (score 4):

First, having multiple tables with the same formats is a sign of bad database design, in general.  It is better to have one table with all the rows.

Second, a hundred tables is starting to get into the limits of what MySQL queries can handle.  The following will not have great performance because it requires sorting all the data, but it should work:

```
select es.*
from (select es.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from ((select employee_id, salary from table001) union all
            . . .
            (select employee_id, salary, from table100)
           ) es cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by salary desc
     ) t
where rn <= @rn * 0.1;
```

This works because after the subquery has enumerated the rows, the variable `@rn` contains the total number of rows.  This can be used for the final filter.

Comment: can you please make me understand the code above. i am not able to get it.

Comment: @user1693842 . . . You use `union all` to bring all the data together.  Enumerate the rows with a variable, in salary order.  This has the side effect of making the variable contain the number of rows in all the tables.  You then select the top 10% using basic arithmetic.